# Why Apache Kafka does not provide a WebSocket connector?

Tags: websocket, apache-kafka

I've seen brokers like [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/web-stomp.html%20or%20https://www.rabbitmq.com/web-mqtt.html) or [Apache Pulsar](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/client-libraries-websocket/) provide a Websocket API to connect directly your browser to the broker.

AFAIK, I've not seen the same for Apache Kafka. You have to implement yourself an intermediary Websocket server.

Why Confluent, which owns Apache Kafka development, does not provide an out-of-the-box websocket API like Rabbitmq or Pulsar ?

Comment: Here's something: https://github.com/Effyis/kafka2websocket

Comment: AFAIK, it is not an official support. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Confluent does not own Apache Kafka development. Apache Kafka is a project owned by the Apache Software Foundation (ASF).

There are several examples of how to use WebSockets with Apache Kafka:

- https://www.confluent.io/blog/data-stream-processing-with-kafka-streams-bitrock-and-confluent/
- https://dev.to/victorgil/kafka-websockets-angular-event-driven-microservices-all-the-way-to-the-frontend-12aa
- https://medium.com/swlh/angular-spring-boot-kafka-how-to-stream-realtime-data-the-reactive-way-510a0f1e5881

Your question seems somewhat a rhetorical one, but if you *actually* would like to see Websockets as part of Apache Kafka then the first step would be to raise a [Kafka Improvement Proposal](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Improvement+Proposals) (KIP) for discussion in the community. There is a [dev mailing list](https://lists.apache.org/list.html?dev@kafka.apache.org) where you can get further guidance on the process on contributing code.

Comment: Here is another example of how to use WebSockets with Apache Kafka, besides the ones provided by @robin-moffatt above. Also, we explain why by simply making available a WebSocket API for Kafka is not sufficient for extending Kafka messaging across the Web:

[https://migratorydata.com/solutions/kafka/](https://migratorydata.com/solutions/kafka/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=forum&utm_campaign=kafka)

Full disclosure: I work for MigratoryData

Answer (score 1):

There is already an open source connecting Kafka with Websocket. https://github.com/b/kafka-websocket

If you have requirements connecting to Kafka from a browser, I suggest to consider to browserfiy this http://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest-node

Answer (score 1):

There is a kafka connector to Ably hosted on the [Confluent Hub](https://www.confluent.io/hub/ably/kafka-connect-ably). Ably is essentially a serverless WebSocket option (with pub/sub and message queues). You will also find a kafka rule on Ably's website.